# Page clear - JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Since I'm using a multipage template for my app, data that I have previously inputted into forms and selects appears when I navigate back to the same page.  I'm looking for a way to wipe the page back to default when a user comes back to it.  On the pages, there are forms, selects, checkboxes and img tags.

This has been suggested to me:

just add custom attribute (like data-default="true") to your default element (for example 0)

but I'd like further clarification if possible.  Thanks

Comment: Would this be after the form has submitted?

Comment: No, even if I type something without submitting, when I navigate back to the page, the stuff I typed is still there

Comment: I think that has to do with your session, and the way the browser is storing it. Not sure what can be done about it.

Comment: It doesn't have nothing to do with sessions, this is just how jQuery Mobile works. I will create you a working solution.

Comment: Thanks Gajotres, that would be very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/vds2U/66/

#### Usage:

Take a look at provided code, every element used has a custom attribute called data-default-value, it is used to determine which element is a default one.

#### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" /> 
        <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>     
        <div data-role="page" id="index" data-theme="a" >
            <div data-role="header">
                <h3>
                    First Page
                </h3>
                <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <input type="button" id="clr-form-btn" value="Clear form"/>
                <label for="basic">Text Input:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="basic" value=""/>

                <label for="flip-1">Flip switch:</label>
                <select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider" data-default-value="off">
                    <option value="off">Off</option>
                    <option value="on">On</option>
                </select>

                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <legend>Choose a pet:</legend>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1"/>
                    <label for="radio-choice-1">Cat</label>

                    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2"  checked="checked" data-default-value=""/>
                    <label for="radio-choice-2">Dog</label>

                    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-3" value="choice-3"  />
                    <label for="radio-choice-3">Hamster</label>

                    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-4" value="choice-4"  />
                    <label for="radio-choice-4">Lizard</label>
                </fieldset>

                <label for="select-choice-0" class="select">Shipping method:</label>
                <select name="select-choice-0" id="select-choice-0" data-default-value="standard">
                    <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
                    <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
                    <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
                    <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
                </select>             
            </div>

            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

            </div>
        </div> 
        <div data-role="page" id="second" data-theme="a" >
            <div data-role="header">
                <h3>
                    Second Page
                </h3>
                <a href="#index" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">

            </div>

            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

            </div>
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

#### Javascript:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    cleanForm();          
});

function cleanForm() {
    var page = $.mobile.activePage;
    // Reset input elements
    page.find('.ui-content *').filter("[type='text']").each(function(){
        $(this).val('');
    });    

    // Reset drop down elements
    page.find('.ui-content *').filter(".ui-select").each(function(){
        var select = $(this).find('select');        
        var defaultValue = select.attr('data-default-value');
        select.val(defaultValue);
        select.selectmenu('refresh', true);
    });    

    // Reset flip switch elements
    page.find('.ui-content *').filter('[data-role="slider"]').each(function(){
        var flipSwitch = $(this);
        var defaultValue = flipSwitch.attr('data-default-value');
        flipSwitch.val(defaultValue);
        flipSwitch.slider('refresh');
    });   

    // Reset radio elements
    page.find('.ui-content *').filter('fieldset:has([type="radio"])').each(function(){
        var radio = $(this);
        var checkedRadio = radio.find(':checked').prop("checked",false).checkboxradio("refresh");
        var defaultRadio = radio.find('[data-default-value]').prop("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome!  I also have an img tag on the page which displays an image taken from the camera, is there a way to clear this back to empty?

Comment: Of course it can be done. Just use this code, filter img elements and cleat src attribute.